# Gson: How to change output of Enum

Tags: java, gson

I've this *enum*:

```
enum RequestStatus {
  OK(200), NOT_FOUND(400);

  private final int code;

  RequestStatus(int code) {
    this.code = code;
  }

  public int getCode() {
    return this.code;
  }
};
```

and in my Request-class, I have this field: `private RequestStatus status`.

When using Gson to convert the Java object to JSON the result is like:

```
"status": "OK"
```

How can I change my GsonBuilder or my Enum object to give me an output like:

```
"status": {
  "value" : "OK",
  "code" : 200
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(new MyEnumAdapterFactory());
```

or more simply (as Jesse Wilson indicated):

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(RequestStatus.class, new MyEnumTypeAdapter());
```

and

```
public class MyEnumAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type) {
            Class<? super T> rawType = type.getRawType();
            if (rawType == RequestStatus.class) {
                return new MyEnumTypeAdapter<T>();
            }
            return null;
    }

    public class MyEnumTypeAdapter<T> extends TypeAdapter<T> {

         public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
              if (value == null) {
                   out.nullValue();
                   return;
              }
              RequestStatus status = (RequestStatus) value;
              // Here write what you want to the JsonWriter. 
              out.beginObject();
              out.name("value");
              out.value(status.name());
              out.name("code");
              out.value(status.getCode());
              out.endObject();
         }

         public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
              // Properly deserialize the input (if you use deserialization)
              return null;
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: @DennisMadsen In here I put it as an inner class of the code. Did you miss it or I didn't understand your question?

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me an example of, how I can change the *JsonWriter* in the write method?

Comment: @DennisMadsen I added some sample code which I think is pretty much what you are looking for.

Comment: FYI, this is awesome. You can save creating the factory class by registering it like this: registerTypeAdapter(RequestStatus, new MyEnumTypeAdapter());

Comment: @JesseWilson Good point. I am just more used to the TypeAdapterFactory.

Comment: What would we need the write method to look like if we want the output to just be: `"status": 200`? Nevermind, it's as simple as just doing `out.value(status.getCode());` without the beginObject part.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet What would be the syntax for the "read" operation?

Comment: @Shark Take a look at the code of `com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter` and see how a object is deserialized. It is simply the same behaviour to implement here.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Polet's answer, if you need a **generic Enum serializer**, you can achieve it via reflection:

```
public class EnumAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory
{

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type)
    {
        Class<? super T> rawType = type.getRawType();
        if (rawType.isEnum())
        {
            return new EnumTypeAdapter<T>();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public class EnumTypeAdapter<T> extends TypeAdapter<T>
    {
        @Override
        public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException
        {
            if (value == null || !value.getClass().isEnum())
            {
                out.nullValue();
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                out.beginObject();
                out.name("value");
                out.value(value.toString());
                Arrays.stream(Introspector.getBeanInfo(value.getClass()).getPropertyDescriptors())
                      .filter(pd -> pd.getReadMethod() != null && !"class".equals(pd.getName()) && !"declaringClass".equals(pd.getName()))
                      .forEach(pd -> {
                          try
                          {
                              out.name(pd.getName());
                              out.value(String.valueOf(pd.getReadMethod().invoke(value)));
                          } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | IOException e)
                          {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                      });
                out.endObject();
            } catch (IntrospectionException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException
        {
            // Properly deserialize the input (if you use deserialization)
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Test
public void testEnumGsonSerialization()
{
    List<ReportTypes> testEnums = Arrays.asList(YourEnum.VALUE1, YourEnum.VALUE2);
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(new EnumAdapterFactory());
    Gson gson = builder.create();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(reportTypes));
}
```

Comment: This is nice but watch out, it serializes getters, not the Enum's fields.