# Gson serialize method not being called

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I'm trying to serialize my objects back to JSON using Google's Gson using JsonSerializer interface and while deserialization works just fine, serialization doesn't call serialize method.

Serializer / Deserializer classes

```
public enum JsonParser implements JsonDeserializer<Object>, JsonSerializer<Object> {
    LANGUAGE(Language.class) {
        @Override
        public Language deserialize(JsonElement elem, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
            return Language.valueOf(elem.getAsString());
        }

        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(Object object, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
            return new JsonPrimitive(((Language) object).getCode());
        }
    },
    DATA_TYPE(DataType.class) {
        @Override
        public DataType deserialize(JsonElement elem, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
            return DataType.getByIdentifier(elem.getAsString());
        }

        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(Object object, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
            System.out.println("test");
            return new JsonPrimitive(((DataType) object).getIdentifier());
        }
    };

    private final Class clazz;
    JsonParser(Class clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Class getParserClass() {
        return clazz;
    }
}
```

And tests:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    for(JsonParser jp : JsonParser.values())
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(jp.getParserClass(), jp);
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    String json = "{\"type1\":{\"da\":\"Some string\",\"pt_BR\":\"More strings\",\"pl\":\"String 3\",\"eo\":\"String 4\"},\"type2\":{\"pl\":\"String 5\",\"pt_BR\":\"String 6\",\"ru\":\"String 7\"}}";
    Map<DataType, Map<Language, String>> map = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<DataType, Map<Language, String>>>(){}.getType());
    System.out.println(map);
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(map));
```

While the fromJson() returns correct objects, toJSON() uses default toString() from objects instead of the methods specified in serialize() method.

It seems that serializer is not getting registered for some reason (the test printout doesn't show up).

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: get ride of the serializer and everything should work correctly

Answer (score 1):

Gson will use the `EnumTypeAdapter` to deserialize your enum, since, if I understood correctly the internals of Gson, this type adapter will be called before than the reflective one, which uses instead your serializer stuff.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297264/gson-how-to-change-output-of-enum) will address you on how you can change the JSON serialization of your enum (using a `TypeAdapter`)

Comment: It's not enums I'm trying to serialize but classes. Enums here are used only to keep all the serializers in one place.

Comment: Could you kindly put also the rest of the code, so that I can understand better what you are trying to do?