# Parsing JSON to Enum Fields

Tags: java, android, json, enums, gson

in my Android application, I am returned a simple JSON object with simple key value pairs, eg:

```
{"username" : "billySmith", "gender" : 1}
```

And an enum with the respective field names `username` and `gender` (String and int, respectively).

I am trying to use Gson to parse the JSON object and populate the enum fields with the json values.  I am a little uncertain of how to use GSON with enums.  I am familiar with the concept that an instance of an object should be set equal to `gson.fromJson(jsonObect, instanceType.class);`.

To add more detail, I am using Enums so that the values can be retrieved from anywhere in my android project.

```
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200 && result != "")
{                               
    GlobalEnum globalEnum = GlobalEnum.getInstance();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    globalEnum = gson.fromJson(result, GlobalEnum.class);
}
```

where "result" is the string representation of an HTTP Response's entity

GlobalEnum snippet:

```
public enum GlobalEnum
{
    INSTANCE;

    private String username;
    private int gender;

    public static GlobalEnum getInstance()
    {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public int getGender()
    {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(int gender)
    {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

*Edit:
Reworded: I have an enum, and I have a jsonObject.  Both the enum and JSON object have "username" and "gender".  using Gson, I would like to parse the JSON object so that the Values from the JSONobject will be assigned to the respective fields in the Enum.

Comment: Can you post the `GlobalEnum` code?

Comment: Take a look at Enums: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: Do you have fixed username/gender values for predefined users?

Comment: [Hope this may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297264/gson-how-to-change-output-of-enum)

Comment: Yes, specifically for testing the app so that I don't have to manually enter the information every time it is run.  But I need to store other things globally across the application, such as an access token generated when logging in

Comment: you need to create a type adapter to be able to parse json to enum, will post an example in few min

Comment: This question is unclear.

Comment: I have given a rewording of the question at the bottom of my post @evertonAgner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have misunderstood the meaning of an `Enum` in Java. They usually shouldn't be opened to modifications on runtime like this.

I guess the following logic would serve you better, saving you from this kind of trouble when parsing `JSON` into `Enums`.

First, a `UserInformation` Java Bean class, wrapping the `username` and `gender` fields:

```
public class UserInformation
{
    private String username;
    private int gender;

    public UserInformation(String username, int gender)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public int getGender()
    {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(int gender)
    {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

Then your `GlobalEnum` class, renamed to `GlobalValues` and modified to work as a value container:

```
public abstract class GlobalValues
{
    // You can also create get/set methods for encapsulation if you want
    public static UserInformation userInformation;
}
```

And then the logic on which you are parsing your `JSON` String into your `UserInformation` object, and then storing it on your `GlobalValues` class.

```
String jsonStr = "{\"username\" : \"billySmith\", \"gender\" : 1}";

Gson gson = new Gson();

GlobalValues.userInformation = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, UserInformation.class);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I understand the logic behind this much more clearly. However I am stuck on an error.

I have initalised the following: `UserInformation userInformation = GlobalValues.userInformation;`.  When I try to call the setters/getters on this instnace I receive a null pointer exception...  Even if I just call `GlobalValues.userInformation` 's getters and setters I still receive the exception..

Comment: The `GlobalValues.userInformation` will remain null until you load them on the first time. You probably have to instantiate and populate your `UserInformation` object and then set them on `GlobalValues.userInformation`.

Comment: I replaced `public static UserInformation userInformation;` in GlobalValue's scope with `public static UserInformation userInformation = new userInformation()` and things seem to work fine now if I reference the instance with GlobalValues.userInformation.  Does this seem reasonable?

Comment: Yeah, you can do that.

Comment: Thank you so much! This actually solved another issue I had before with GSON as well!

Comment: New Issue...Whenever you call `gson.fromJson(jsonStr, UserInformation.class)` on `GlobalValues.userInformation`, it wipes all fields that were not within the json string (sets to null)?

Comment: It's not that it wipes them. It creates a new UserInformation instance. If you pass it as it is on GlobalValues.userInformation, in practice you'll wipe the other fields' values. You may need to implement a `merge` method (or look up for an existing lib) to do that.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment you need create a type adapter to be able to get your enum during json parsing. This is an example of what i have done for my purposes.
In your enum create `TypeAdapterFactory gsonTypeAdaptor` like so:

```
public static TypeAdapterFactory gsonTypeAdaptor = new TypeAdapterFactory() {
        @Override
        public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
            Class<T> rawType = (Class<T>) type.getRawType();
            if (!(rawType.isEnum() && Predicates.assignableFrom(rawType).apply(<your enum>.class))) {
                return null;
            }
            return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
                public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                    if (value == null) {
                        out.nullValue();
                    } else {
                        out.value(((<your enum>)value).name);
                    }
                }
                public T read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
                    if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
                        reader.nextNull();
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        return (T) <get your enum by using reader.nextString()>;
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    };
```

one adapter is in place, register it with your `gson builder` like so:
`builder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(<your enum>.gsonTypeAdaptor);`

Let me know if this was useful.